# How to code the value of input[type="submit"] that validates

Tags: html, forms, validation, encoding, glyph

**Two questions**

1. What is the best way to encode the rarer characters for form element values?
2. Is the semi-colon in the example below causing the validation error or is it something else?

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="&#61442;">
```

Validation Error:

```
Document uses the Unicode Private Use Area(s), 
which should not be used in publicly exchanged documents. (Charmod C073)
```

The value of this element is causing the error. I need to recode this decimal value to something that will render my glyph and also validates.

Answer (score 4):

1. It does not really matter much. A decimal character reference and a hexadecimal character reference both work OK (with no real difference). Using the character as such in UTF-8 encoded document may make the code more readable, though then the encoding *must* be UTF-8 and *must* be declared as UTF-8. And in the case of a Private Use code point, which is what you are using, when viewing source, programs may show it as just about anything. Private Use code points have no defined meaning; any allocation of a character to such a code point is up to an agreement between interested parties. And your favorite code editor has hardly made such and agreement.
2. No, the semicolon is correct. The warning (not error message) is not based on any HTML specification or draft but on the W3C recommendation known as [CharMod](http://www.w3.org/TR/charmod/) (Character Model for the World Wide Web 1.0: Fundamentals). The warning refers to item C073 there: “Publicly interchanged content SHOULD NOT use codepoints in the private use area.”

On the practical side, the code fails whenever a specific, privately encoded font is not used, e.g. because the browser has been set to ignore font faces suggested on web pages or because the font fails to load. It is thus better to use an image, with an appropriate `alt` text, using either `<input type=image>` or `<button>` containing `<img>`.

Comment: The image will fail, too, if it fails to load, if users have disabled images (as I do on my mobile phone to save expensive bandwidth), or if blind people access your site. Also, images are larger than fonts, and (since SVG support is declining) don't scale as well. Using fonts for social icon links has become the defacto standard today. Specs need to be updated to allow for this use.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to encode the rarer characters for form element values?

Plain UTF-8. It produces the most readable source code and uses the fewest bytes.

> Is the semi-colon in the example below causing the validation error or is it something else?

No, it is the choice of character. It isn't one that is part of unicode standard. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29) for more details.

Comment: Thx. Is there some work-around? This character is used in a icon font. I need to find some way I can continue to use this character, use it in a form and have it validate?

Comment: I hope not. It renders as an unprintable character when I try to use it, so I assume that you are depending on the browser using a specific font applied through your CSS. This is a terrible idea (read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)). If you want an icon in your submit button then use `<button type="submit"><img src="icon.png" alt="sensible alternative text"></button>`.

Comment: Ok Thx Quentin. I am familiar with progressive enhancement and was not reliant on the character alone to communicate the function, but the completeness of your answers is great.

Comment: Private Use code points *are* part of the Unicode Standard. But the standard does not allocate, and will never allocate, any characters to them, leaving them as a playground for private games.

Comment: Using icon fonts through css is quite a normal thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly nuanced answer to a related question on [TeamTreeHouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/-document-uses-the-unicode-private-use-areas), where validator failed for an icon used in a navigation menu (which was also my case).

> I wouldn't worry too much about this one as it's a warning not an
> error. I would keep the semi-colon if that's what the icon
> documentation suggests (looks like you're using IcoMoon?).
>
> IcoMoon's explanation for the use of using the Private Use Area is:
>
> Using Latin letters is not recommended for icons fonts. Using the
> Private Use Area of Unicode is the best option for icon fonts. By
> using PUA characters, your icon font will be compatible with screen
> readers. But if you use Latin characters, the screen reader might read
> the single meaning less letters, which would be confusing.
>
> Here is a link to some people arguing over whether it is good use or
> not.
>
> Hundreds of sites sites use the code from IcoMoon with no issue.